# animate the increasement of a score

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, label

SO I have a label `labelscore` and it increase of 1000 every time there is a collision between two images. I would like to see `labelscore` increase of 1000 like an animated score, a running score. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an NSTimer to call a routine every 16.7 to 50 milliseconds.  In the routine increment some value and update it to the label.  Rinse and repeat until this value is equal to the score.  This is the basic technique of an animation game loop.

You have the option to use a repeating timer and invalidate it when you're done with it.  Or setting single-shot timers within each update routine for the next iteration.  You could also use CADisplayLink as an alternative to NSTimer, which may provide smoother animation under some conditions.

Comment: sorry but can you explain more the part You can use an NSTimer to call a routine every 16.7 to 50 milliseconds. In the routine increment some value and update it to the label. Rinse and repeat until this value is equal to the score I don't really understand I'm new to xcode. if you have a little part of a code it would be great :)

Comment: Search for NSTimer in Apple's documentation, and for the many many examples of its use on this site ?